# Cross account S3 static website access over VPN only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-vpn

I'm trying to allow access to s3 bucket static website over VPN from network aws account , bucket in prod account.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "account-prod",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-1"
                }
            }
        }
       {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "account-network",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-2"  <<<>>> tried SourceVpce as well           
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I used VPC endpoint interface in the account where VPN is setup , I tried using Condition SourceVpc and SourceVpce but non worked.

I'm using transit gateway and aws client vpn and allowed s3 endpoint IPs on the vpn endpoint + SGs + auth rules. (tgw is used and s3 prefix list, route entry from s3 prefix list via tgw)

bucket uses object owner + private ACL + bucket policy and I tried adding grantee with the canonical account id.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here ?

This currently works in the prod account as we have another VPN solution that runs there, we are trying to migrate everything to network account and move to aws client vpn.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas what am I doing wrong here ?

Yes. s3 bucket static website can only be accesses **over the Internet**. You can't access them using private IP addresses from VPC or VPN. If you use VPN, you have to setup some proxy which will access the website using the internet, and then pass it back to your host.

Comment: but it works fine with wireguard  which is another solution that runs in the prod account and the policy of the bucket allow the vpc-1 as above.

Comment: Worth mentioning I'm able to list objects (s3api) when using gateway endpoint but not interface ( test done from private ec2 instance that runs in the same VPN associated subnets but curl-ING the static website on s3 fails in both cases, 403 / timeout

Comment: I'm able to list objects over the awsclient vpn connection and from an ec2 in the vpn subnet ,                                                                                                                                                  whether I use a condition to restrict access to vpce /vpc on the bucket policy  or not.  (using vpc gateway endpoint) but the static website still returns 403

Comment: @MOps static websites don't work over vpc endpoints. Not sure what is not clear about my anwser? Listing objects and hosting websites are two different things.

Comment: Thank you , apologies I was confused that it could be possible but I think we will use cloudfront or use a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your VPC Subnet route table has a route to the S3 endpoint, and the policy for the endpoint is giving access.

https://tomgregory.com/when-to-use-an-aws-s3-vpc-endpoint/

next, setup your bucket policy as below, try to give access from the source of your VPC Endpoint, and not the VPC itself. (note the vpce in the policy doc).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html

Comment: s3 interface type endpoint does not use that , it creates ENI in the same VPC which is the one I use for my VPN awscvpn endpoint. I did try to allow access using source vpce , and testing with vpc and non worked , in both cases I get 403 forbidden on the bucket

Comment: I tested using different vpc endpoints :                                                                                       -s3 interface > vpc(vpn endpoint) > 403 forbidden                                                                                     -using s3 gateway endpoint > vpc ( vpn endpoint has routes for s3 prefix> vpce)                 from private ec2 instance in the same subnet getting 403 forbidden ( bucket policy allows access from account-network with condition vpc endpoint id                                        so far non worked ,

Comment: Does the requesting principal have the right policy? IE the instance role has S3 get/list?

Comment: Can you run the access analyser against the ec2 and the endpoint?

Comment: I'm using bucket policy for that , its a static website , and I provided access for the root of the network account in the policy . access analyzer looks good , did not give any issues and looks like it passes to the endpoint , but I'm not sure if VPN endpoint split tunnel causes that since I'm using it on the endpoint ( traffic goes over internet instead of through the tunnel)

Comment: I'm sorry I did not clarify , I was testing curl http://s3bucketstaticwebsiteurl  so in terms of s3api I did test and it works listing objects but I want to allow access to static website and reading objects to run the storybookUI website  https://storybook.js.org/